# cURL not returning anything?

Tags: php, curl

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
$config = array
(
    "siteURL"        => "http://domain.com",
    "loginCheck"     => "checkuser.php",
    "userAgent"      => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/10.0.648.204 Safari/534.16"
);

$postFields = "username=user&password=pass&submit= Login ";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $config['siteURL'] . $config['loginCheck']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, config['userAgent']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, config['siteURL']);

$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $content;

?>
```

I expect this to be echoing the result of the curl, but its not. am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: try some debugging stuff, e.g. `var_dump($content);`, `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);` and `var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));` -- you might be getting a zero length response, or cURL might be encountering some kind of connection error.

Comment: Is the page you're `cURL`ing to set up correctly? Just a stupid mistake that I've made PLENTY of times in the past.

Comment: Always use this: error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1); If you don't want the error messages mess up your HTML result, write them to a log file.

Comment: @Dereleased, it's returning bool(false) - @esqew, yes it's set up correctly. - @Stefan Pantke, `error_reporting(-1)` is equivalent to E ALL, and I'm outputting it to a terminal.

Comment: Adding to Stefan's comment, you can create a simple (but **very useful**) "debugger" script by combining `register_shutdown_function()` with `error_get_last()`.

Comment: Actually E_ALL is 30719 (as of PHP 5.3). There is no equivalent error constant for -1. However, `error_reporting()` seems to convert -1 to E_ALL. The major difference is that you can, eg; remove E_PARSE out of E_ALL, but not E_PARSE out of -1. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does, if you set a complete URL with a '/' at the end (fix two other typos):

```
error_reporting(-1);
$config = array
(
    "siteURL"        => "http://www.apple.com/",
    "loginCheck"     => "checkuser.php",
    "userAgent"      => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/10.0.648.204 Safari/534.16"
);

$postFields = "username=user&password=pass&submit= Login ";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $config['siteURL'] . $config['loginCheck']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $config['userAgent']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $config['siteURL']);

$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $content;
```

Comment: Shit I forgot the /, I meant to get that later, but forgot about it. Works now, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

If curl doesn't return anything then you have to check for the reason why that happen. Check for the last curl error message:

```
if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
    echo 'Operation completed without any errors, you have the response';
}
```

Basically it would be good to always check on that. You shouldn't assume that curl request succeeded.

Comment: How can I know the date of the error? To know if the error is from this request or another.

Comment: When you have the error (first section of if condition) you can get also current date/time and print/save it. You don't need to get it from curl library.

Answer (score 1):

Two of your variables are named badly:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, config['userAgent']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, config['siteURL']);
```

Should be:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $config['userAgent']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $config['siteURL']);
```

My guess is that PHP faulted to a blank page (since the variable is seen as a constant but constants must be scalar).

Another issue may be the user agent. I've seen servers that completely refuse to reply if no user agent was set.

Comment: No, the original problem was related to this string "http://www.apple.com", which should read "http://www.apple.com/".

Comment: Actually, syntax errors are found and reported before real code execution, so the problem I reported *had to be fixed earlier*.

Comment: Sure. You are right. But even with these two fixes, the code echoed noting - due to the malformed URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a class that I wrote that wraps around CURL. To install, see: https://github.com/homer6/altumo

It's much easier to use and can give you some easy to access debugging. For example:

```
try{

    //load class autoloader
        require_once( __DIR__ . '/loader.php' );  //you should ensure that is is the correct path for this file

    //make the response; return the response with the headers
        $client = new \Altumo\Http\OutgoingHttpRequest( 'http://www.domain.com/checkuser.php', array(
            'username' => 'user',
            'password' => 'pass',
            'submit' => ' Login '
        ));
        $client->setRequestMethod( \Altumo\Http\OutgoingHttpRequest::HTTP_METHOD_POST );

    //send the request (with optional arguments for debugging)           
        //the first true will return the response headers
        //the second true will turn on curl info so that it can be retrieved later
        $response = $client->send( true, true );

    //output the response and curl info
        \Altumo\Utils\Debug::dump( $response, $client->getCurlInfo() );

    //alternatively, you can get the response wrapped in an object that allows you to retrieve parts of the response
        $http_response =  $client->sendAndGetResponseMessage( true );
        $status_code = $http_response->getStatusCode();
        $message_body = $http_response->getMessageBody();
        $full_http_response = $http_response->getRawHttpResponse();
        \Altumo\Utils\Debug::dump( $status_code, $message_body, $full_http_response );


}catch( \Exception $e ){

    //This will display an error if any exceptions have been thrown
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();

}
```

Hope that helps...