# header information in image file uploaded via php curl library

Tags: php, image, curl, upload, header

I am using php's curl library to upload images. I have a problem. It seems that some header information is saved in the image file and the image can't be viewed until these are removed.

------------------------------4954a272dea2^M
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="WorkingMan1122.jpg"^M
Content-Type: image/jpeg^M
^M
followed by the image

I looked at the header of the request and it looks like:

Array (     [Authorization] => Basic ZGF2aWRwK2FwaV91c2VyQHpvb3NrLmNvbTzl1bVV5RzNyTnNydU1Ma1VNQ0ZpS0pzeXY=     [Host] => www.....com     [Accept] => */*     [Content-Length] => 220803     [Expect] => 100-continue     [Content-type] => application/binary; boundary=----------------------------4954a272dea2 )

Is the server not handling the request correctly or is it my (the client's) problem?

Answer (score 0):

See my previous reponse on troubleshooting CURL. Let me know if you need some more clarification.

[cURL not returning anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797112/curl-not-returning-anything/5797427#5797427)