# What is wrong with this cURL post in PHP versus a straight HTML post?

Tags: php, curl

The following HTML form posts to remote, external server with success, but my slightly more secure cURL post from a PHP script fails.  I don't receive any error information via my script, and the remote party has not been able to furnish any, so my question actually boils down to, what the critical difference between the two post requests is.

The winner:

```
<form name="frm" action="http://wow.aspx" method="post">
<input type="HIDDEN" name="q1" value="charlesmanson">
<input type="HIDDEN" name="q2" value="batman@home.net">
<input type="HIDDEN" name="q3" value="20110428092741">
<input type="HIDDEN" name="q4" value="6E1AAB44-7508-4BF4-ADA8-0535E880A996">
<input type="submit" value="Go for it!" />
</form>
```

And the loser:

```
$curlSession = curl_init('http://nowbitch.aspx');
curl_setopt ($curlSession, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($curlSession, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "q1=$userLogin&q2=$userRecord[email]&q3=$timeStamp&q4=$hash");
curl_setopt ($curlSession, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_exec ($curlSession);
curl_close ($curlSession);
```

Real parameters have been lost to protect the guilty.

Comment: You must add a final slash to the URL. `curl_init('http://nowbitch.aspx');` => `curl_init('http://nowbitch.aspx/');`

Comment: Try using a utility like Wireshark or Fiddler2 to intercept the actual HTTP request being generated when you submit the form.  Make sure you copy all the headers, and also the value of `curl_init()` there doesn't appear to be a valid URL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [cURL not returning anything?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797112/curl-not-returning-anything)

Comment: "Real parameters have been lost to protect the guilty" ... so, Charles Manson is innocent?

Comment: AJ, no, but the people I'm putting myself through this for are, sort of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this logic, it facilitate the debugging of curl requests. The main is to `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` and `curl_getinfo`.

```
$ch = curl_init();
...

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

if ($result === false || $info['http_code'] != 200) {
    // ERROR
} else {
    // OK
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) POST to Action: http://wow.aspx: so `curl_init('http://wow.aspx');`

2.) Use REFERER: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://nowbitch.aspx');`